# How to find and update a record (MongoDB) by its _id using a button in ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to update a record in Mongodb by clicking on a button rendered using ejs templates. 
I will have two buttons, an accept button that will update the "Booked" attribute to "true" and "requested" attribute to false.
a reject button that will update both the "Booked" and "requested" attribute to false.

right now, im only working on the accept button and its id is detal. here is the script part of the ejs file:

```
<script>

          const button = document.getElementById('detal');         
                       button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                           fetch('/dashboard/requests/details/5c951ade25d3c63298e8e8b2',{
                               method: "put",
                               headers : {
                               "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                           },

                           })  
                       });


           </script>
```

I am inserting the record _id manually for now, however, i would like the set the record _id to a variable and insert it in the fetch function.

This is my put method in app.js :

```
app.put('/dashboard/requests/details/:id', function acceptReq(req, res){
    const reqID = req.params.id;
    var query = { _id: ObjectId(reqID)};
    console.log(reqID)

    db.getDB().collection(collection).findOneAndUpdate({query}, { $set: { 
        requested: false,
        requests:{
        user: undefined,
        time: undefined
        },
        Booked:true

        }}, { returnOriginal: false }, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            req.flash(
            'success_msg',
            'Request Accepted!'
            );
            res.redirect('/dashboard/requests')
            }
    });
});
```

the console.log will print reqID in my console however, it seems like the update of the database does not happen.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "findOneAndUpdate(query, ... " without the curly braces around query, that's what looks wrong in the first look to me.

Comment: I've tried that, and it works now. However i still get an 404 error like : PUT http://localhost:5000/dashboard/requests/details/5c951ade25d3c63298e8e8b2
whenever i click on the button. Also the its suppose to redirect me to another page but it doesn't? 
The record is updated on the database though!